# How to rotate a group of objects together

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

How can I rotate a group of objects together, that is, I don't want to rotate each object individually, because that way they will collide.

Here is an example when rotating individually:

[image: rotate-wrong]

I need to rotate the entire group, so I would have this result:

[image: rotate]

I tried in several ways to create a function with JavaScript capable of doing this calculation, but every attempt I made was not correct.

```
interface Plate {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  angle: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface RotateGroup {
  plates: Plate[];
  centerX: number;
  centerY: number;
  angle: number;
}

interface GroupInfo {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  centerX: number;
  centerY: number;
  area: number;
}

function calculateGroupArea(plates: Plate[]): GroupInfo {
  let minX = Infinity;
  let minY = Infinity;
  let maxX = -Infinity;
  let maxY = -Infinity;

  plates.forEach(plate => {
    minX = Math.min(minX, plate.x);
    minY = Math.min(minY, plate.y);
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, plate.x + plate.width);
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, plate.y + plate.height);
  });

  const width = maxX - minX;
  const height = maxY - minY;
  const area = width * height;

  const centerX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
  const centerY = (minY + maxY) / 2;

  return {
    x: minX,
    y: minY,
    centerX,
    centerY,
    area,
  };
}

function rotateGroup({
  plates,
  centerX,
  centerY,
  angle,
}: RotateGroup): Plate[] {
  const rad = angle * (Math.PI / 180); // Converting degrees to radians

  plates.forEach(plate => {
    // Translate plate to origin
    const translatedX = plate.x - centerX;
    const translatedY = plate.y - centerY;

    // Rotate the plate
    const rotatedX = translatedX * Math.cos(rad) - translatedY * Math.sin(rad);
    const rotatedY = translatedX * Math.sin(rad) + translatedY * Math.cos(rad);

    // Translate the plate back
    plate.x = rotatedX + centerX;
    plate.y = rotatedY + centerY;

    // Update the angle of the plate
    plate.angle += angle;
  });

  return plates;
}

const plates: Plate[] = [
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    angle: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 100,
  },
  {
    x: 60,
    y: 10,
    angle: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 100,
  },
  {
    x: 110,
    y: 10,
    angle: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 100,
  },
];

console.log('calculateGroupArea: ', calculateGroupArea(plates));
console.log(
  'rotateGroup: ',
  rotateGroup({
    plates,
    angle: 45,
    centerX: 85,
    centerY: 60,
  }),
);
```

The result always looks like this:

[image: rotate-wrong-2]

Comment: Mathematically speaking you rotate multiple objects together by applying the same rotation to them. A mathematical rotation is typically defined in global coordinates, not local to any single object. So your problem is not do much about mathematics but more about how to formulate that for your environment